# How to get parent pk in django rest framework nested route using GenericAPIView?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've create the nested route by using https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers, but I don't know how to get the parent pk inside viewset

Sample route: /group/8/users

In view.py

```
class UserViewSet(ListModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView, viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.filter(group_pk=group_pk) <-------how to get group_pk
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `get_queryset` function instead, then you would have access to `self.kwargs` which contains your parent model lookup field and value from the router.

```
class UserViewSet(...):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(
            group_pk=self.kwargs.get('group_pk'))
```